# How to add ggproto objects together and save for later without call to ggplot()?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to save some specifications of a ggplot command for later, given that I need to run several different graphs that all share some scale aesthetics.

Let's say I would like save this for later:

```
my.scale_aes <- scale_x_continuous(...) + scale_color_manual(...)
```

This would of course prompt an error message, indicating that you cannot add ggproto objects together without a direct `ggplot()` call. But is that really the case? And is there another way by which I could still add these components together?

I read somewhere else that it has to do with the different methods of adding elements together: `methods("+")` and that what I need has something to do with `+.gg*` but I have no idea how to implement this and how to make it work.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can do this by defining a list of the `ggplot` terms you want and adding them in.

```
library(ggplot2)

my.scales <- list(
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(56, 60, 61)),
  scale_color_manual(values = c("black", "red"))
)

ggplot(data = diamonds[1:100,],
       aes(depth, price, color = cut == "Ideal")) +
  geom_point() +
  my.scales
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I had tried with a vector, which does not work for some reason: `Error: Can't add \`o\` to a ggplot object.` It works fine as a list.

Comment: Simple and flawless answer, thank you @jon-spring , you really saved my day! FYI, I was looking for such a solution in a context when I calculate layers as part a Shiny reactive(), and use these layers in a ggplot/plotly output. Works 100% now. Thanks!