# R: control multiple graphs design together using ggplot2 ggarrange

Tags: r, ggplot2

Can I design multiple graphs combined with `ggplot2` `ggarrange`? I would like to `scale_colour_manual` and choose the background, panel grid, etc all together instead of designing each one separately and then combining them.
tnx!

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including the code you have tried and a snippet of your data or some fake data.

Comment: You can specify common theme, scale, and layers by putting them in a list and adding that to each plot: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56411380/6851825